# How to save old IDs / reference numbers from several models?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

what is the best conceptional way to save old IDs / reference numbers from several models?

For example:

```
 class Project(models.Model):
     reference_number = models.CharField(_('Project ID'), max_length=16,
        unique=True)

 class Offer(models.Model):
     reference_number = models.CharField(_('Offer ID'), max_length=16,
        unique=True)
```

**My ideas:**

1. A separated model for each of the models

   ```
   class OldProjectNumber(models.Model):
       project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
       old_number = models.CharField(_('Old ID'), max_length=16,
           unique=True)

   ...
   ```
2. One model for all the models?

   ```
   class OldNumber(models.Model):
       project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
       offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
       old_number = models.CharField(_('Old ID'), max_length=16,
           unique=True)
   ```
3. Something else?

Maybe a [CommaSeparatedCharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) to keep the values in the model itself?

I need to be able to search / filter for the old reference numbers for each model.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: 2nd model looks good if you already have existing DB. You can use One2One relation in case they are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many old reference will be there.

If there will be only a few old reference numbers you can use  `CommaSeparatedCharField` but in this you will have to specify the max_length which will limit it to few reference numbers and cause problem anytime in future.

I would suggest you to use a textfield and use a json formatted string to store the list of old references.

If the count of reference number can get large, you should use One models for all the models to store the reference number.

Also, Instead of using a foreign key for each of one of models you should use generic foreign key which will map to all other models.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class OldNumber(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and Generic Relation on the model itself.

```
old_reference = GenericRelation('OldNumber', related_query_name='model_name')  # related_query_name for reverse querying
```

Comment: If you are sure you will have only 2 models for old references you can use 2 foreign keys but it is not scale able. If you want references for many models you should definitely go for generic foreign keys